# How to properly emit an event passed as a string parameter to emit() function?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, emit

What I'm trying to do is to pass the emit name as a string (e.g. `'showComponent'`) from child to parent, then evoke another emit in `emitAction(callbackName: string)`, and eventually call the `showComponent()` function.

There are no errors or warnings. What am I doing wrong?

*Parent component:*

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const showLoginPopup: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);

function showComponent() {
  showLoginPopup.value = true;
}

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: string): void;
}>()


function emitAction(callbackName: string) {
  emit(callbackName);
}

</script>

<template>
<ActionVue @emitAction="emitAction" v-for="action in actions"
            :title="action.title"
            :description="action.description"
            :buttonTitle="action?.buttonTitle"
            :actionType="action.actionType" />
</template>
```

*Child component:*

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<Action>();
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: 'emitAction', callbackName: string): void;
}>()

</script>

<template>
    <button @click="emit('emitAction', props.actionType)">
     {{  props.buttonTitle }}
    </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Is there an error or something? What *are* you doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I haven’t mentioned it in my question. There are no errors or warnings.

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing and what do you expect?

Comment: @ConnorLow I expect the function ´showComponent()´ fires after ´emit(callbackName)´ got ´showComponent’ string as parameter.

Comment: Where are you listening for your emitted event? Is your child component in `ActionVue`? Are you certain your events are even reaching the parent component? Note that `emit` doesn't automagically call your components' methods.

Comment: @ConnorLow Yes, `ActionVue` is the child component. The first `emit` from the `ActionVue` reaches `emitAction(callbackName: string)` in the parent component. But the `emit` *inside* `emitAction` never gets called. So yes, now I understand that `emit` function only works within template and only evokes functions defined in parent component.

Comment: Have you tried changing the listener to `@emit-action="..."` (kebab-case instead of camelCase)? I've been snagged on that before. [See the docs for an example](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events)

Answer (score 1):

A second emit isn't going to do anything except emit the event up to the parent's parent component.  I would recommend simply running the function based on the emit name

child:

```html
<button @click="emit('showComponent')"
```

parent:

```html
<ActionVue @showComponent="showComponent()">
```

If you *really* want to call a function based on a string value, you can dynamically call the function stored on the current app instance:

Parent component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
    const app = getCurrentInstance()

    function emitAction(callbackName: string) {
          // if callbackName === 'showComponent', runs function showComponent()
          app.setupState[callbackName](); 
    }

    function showComponent() {
        showLoginPopup.value = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @yoduh your way seems to be valid, but in my case I can't use `setupState` method because it's marked as `/* Excluded from this release type: setupState */` in Vue runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `emit` within the `template` markup, it needs to be `$emit(…)`.  See my [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Made-of-Clay/pen/RwMXvOZ?editors=1010), specifically how I'm calling emit in the child components.

```html
<!-- works -->
<button @click="$emit('foo', 'bar')">Click</button>
<!-- does not work; "emit" is not a defined function for the component -->
<button @click="emit('foo', 'bar')">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AdamLeis. However, this part of my code works fine with simple `emit()`. I think I have to clarify that I'm using **setup** syntax with TS.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't think using script setup would affect the `emit` function. Maybe it gets exposed automatically for script setup. *Update:* never mind, I see the `const emit = ...`